# PHP session variables do not store integer values

Tags: php

I'm creating a user login in PHP. I have written the following code to get some fields from the database. The id and user_role are integers which are the only fields that return null when set to a session variable. I can't figure out what the problem is.

```
$q = "SELECT id, password, last_name, user_role, first_name FROM users WHERE email=?";
$statement = $con->prepare($q);
$statement->bind_param("s", $email);
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->get_result();

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $result = $result->fetch_assoc();
    $password_hash = $result['password'];
    if (passwordVerify($password, $password_hash)) {
        $_SESSION['user_role'] = $result['user_role']; // set user role to session
        $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
        $_SESSION['id'] = $result['id'];
        $_SESSION['last_name'] = $result['last_name'];
        $_SESSION['first_name'] = $result['first_name'];
        header('Location: index.php');
    } else {
        $_SESSION['msg'] = "Invalid Password/ Email Address";
    }
} else {
    $_SESSION['msg'] = "Invalid Password/ Email Address";
}
```

When I echo `$_SESSION['email']` it displays the email but when I echo `$_SESSION['id']` it displays nothing.

`echo $result['id']` displays the id.

**Edit**

sample `var_dump($result);` and `var_dump($_SESSION);` output

```
array (size=5)
    'user_role' => int 2
    'email' => string 'sample@gmail.com' (length=16)
    'id' => int 30
    'last_name' => string 'Doe' (length=3)
    'first_name' => string 'John' (length=4)
```

`echo $_SESSION['email']` outputs sample@gmail.com

`echo $_SESSION['id']` is blank

Comment: I dont't see the session_start(), do you have it ?

Comment: var_dump($result); var_dump($_SESSION);

Comment: Yes! It's in a file that is included to the file containing the script. The varchar fields are OK just those returning integer values not working.

Comment: var_dump($result); and var_dump($_SESSION); return the expected result.

Comment: How can var_dump $_SESSION show that it contains the correct value, but echo does not? Is something changing between the var dump and the echo ?

Comment: Are you also changing session values on `index.php` page? It seems like `id` and `user_role` are getting replaced in `index.php` file before you try to print it.. otherwise, it must not give this weird error.

Comment: The index page contained just the `echo` statement. I just refreshed again and it works without me changing anything. Weird. Is this common?

Comment: Just to note that in first run session is set but will not be readable and will not echo out, and when you refresh the page, session will be readable and show up using echo.